# Can't find a constant-time module in cryptography package used on AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, paramiko, aws-lambda, pycrypto

*[I am new to Python 2.7 and AWS Lambda, any help is appreciated]*

I followed the [AWS Lambda tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/scheduling-ssh-jobs-using-aws-lambda/) and created a virtualenv to include Python libs associated with the use of paramiko to copy a file to an SFTP server as a scheduled task on AWS Lambda to run the following script:

```
import paramiko

def worker_handler(event, context):

    host = "sftpserver.testdpom.com" 
    port = 22
    transport = paramiko.Transport((host, port))

    sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)

    username = "xxxx"
    password = "xxxxxx"

    transport.connect(username = username, password = password)

    sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)

    sftp.put("test.txt", "test.txt")
    sftp.close()
    transport.close()

    return
    {
        'message' : "Script execution completed. See Cloudwatch logs for complete output"
    }
```

The python script works correctly on my local machine but when I test the package on AWS Lambda, I get the error "ImportError: No module named _constant_time" and stack trace below.

**Can you think of any possible reason for this error in AWS Lambda environment?**

```
  File "/var/task/paramiko/kex_group1.py", line 111, in _parse_kexdh_reply
    self.transport._verify_key(host_key, sig)
  File "/var/task/paramiko/transport.py", line 1617, in _verify_key
    key = self._key_info[self.host_key_type](Message(host_key))
  File "/var/task/paramiko/rsakey.py", line 58, in __init__
    ).public_key(default_backend())
  File "/var/task/cryptography/hazmat/backends/__init__.py", line 35, in default_backend
    _default_backend = MultiBackend(_available_backends())
  File "/var/task/cryptography/hazmat/backends/__init__.py", line 22, in _available_backends
    "cryptography.backends"
  File "/var/task/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2235, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/var/task/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.backend import backend
  File "/var/task/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py", line 15, in <module>
    from cryptography import utils, x509
  File "/var/task/cryptography/x509/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from cryptography.x509.base import (
  File "/var/task/cryptography/x509/base.py", line 15, in <module>
    from cryptography.x509.extensions import Extension, ExtensionType
  File "/var/task/cryptography/x509/extensions.py", line 19, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import constant_time, serialization
  File "/var/task/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/constant_time.py", line 9, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._constant_time import lib
ImportError: No module named _constant_time
```

Comment: getting same error message using lambda

Comment: Same here too. Any luck?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since lambda runs under the hood on amazon linux instances, you basically need to:

1. spin up an amazon linux ec2 instance
2. create a virtualenv and `pip install` all packages you need
3. `scp` the files down to wherever your local deployment package lives

This all happens due to issues with how `pip install` does things differently depending on whether you're on linux or mac (and I'm assuming windows as well).

#### here's a startup script to get the ec2 instance up to speed afaik

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo yum upgrade -y
sudo yum group install -y "Development tools"

sudo yum install -y \
    python27 \
    libffi libffi-devel \
    openssl openssl-devel

virtualenv venv
source venv/bin/activate

pip install paramiko
```

The `paramiko` package will be in `/path/to/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko` and the `cryptography` stuff will be in `path/to/venv/lib64/python2.7/cryptography`.

I've been using a combination of `pip install` on my local mac and doing this when a package doesn't work (like for `paramiko` and `psycopg2`), and there are a few other helpful packages that people have pre-compiled and put up on github elsewhere specifically for lambda.

HTH!

Comment: another decent solution is to use an amazon-linux docker container to do all of the above